# Incompatible operand types Scanner and String?

Tags: java, string, compiler-errors, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

I keep getting the following errors:

- Incompatible operand types Scanner
  and String
- Incompatible operand types int and
  String
  before I added the int op = Integer.valueOf(operator) line it kept giving me errors when I would name my cases. I'm still very new it's the second code I've written for my class so please keep the explanation simple if at all possible (there is also a calculator class not shown here if there's any confusion about that) :

````
//change the package name to calculatorClass///////////////

import java.util.Scanner;

public class assignmentB {

    public static String String(int y,int x, String name, String str) throws Exception {
        if (y < 1)
            throw new Exception("Value must be larger than 0.");
        if (x < 1)
            throw new Exception("Value must be larger than 0");
        return name;
        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Calculator c1 = new Calculator();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        c1.name = "The total is $";
    
try {
    }   catch (Exception e1){
        System.out.println(e1);
    }
    {
        
        int x, y, s, a, m;
        String name1;
        
        
        System.out.println("Red River College");
        System.out.println("Custom Calculator");
        
        System.out.println("Enter first value: ");
        x = input.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Enter second value: ");
        y = input.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Enter operation(a=Add, s=Subtract, m=multiply): ");
        String operator = input.nextLine();
        int op =Integer.valueOf(operator);
        
        switch (op) {
        case 1:
            if (input == "s") {
            System.out.println(c1.name + c1.subtract(x,y));
            }
        case 2:
            if (input == "a") {
            System.out.println(c1.name + c1.add(x,y));
            }
        case 3:
            if (input == "m") {
            System.out.println(c1.name + c1.multiply(x,y));
            }
        }
        
     
        
    }   
    }
}

    ```
````

Comment: Please provide the *exact* error message and indicate which line and column it occurs on. But you appear to have your `op` variable and your `Scanner` variable mixed up. And once you know the operator you don't need to do another test: the `case` takes you to the right place.

Answer (score 5):

You have defined `input` to be a `Scanner`, with this line:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

You can then use `input` to do scanner things, as you're doing here:

```
x = input.nextInt();
```

So far so good.

But later in the code, you do this (and a few variations that are similar):

```
if (input == "s") {
    ...
}
```

This isn't valid. The Java compiler is telling you that it will not allow you to use `==` to compare a `Scanner` (that is, `input`) against a String (which in this example is "s"). The compiler is giving you an error to say: `input == "s"` isn't allowed.

It isn't clear what your intent is (that is, how you want the code to actually behave), but the issue is definitely with those three `if` statements. Each is attempting to compare a `java.util.Scanner` with a `java.lang.String` (one is "s", one is "a", the last is "m"). So you'll need to fix those to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

As a *guess*, maybe you want to read a new String input from the scanner, and then compare that to "s", etc.? If so, that could look something like below. Note that to compare strings you should use `equals()` (*don't* use `==` to compare strings, or any other objects).

```
String newString = input.next();
switch (op) {
    case 1:
        if (newString.equals("s")) {
            System.out.println(c1.name + c1.subtract(x, y));
        }
    ...
}
```